# How to build a "virtual zippo" app?

Tags: iphone, video, uiview, uitouch

You probably all know the famous virtual zippo app.

I thought of making such an app too, just for learning objective-c.
THe developer said he has used a video of flame.

How is it possible to play a video inside a UIView?

DO you have any ideas of how to achieving that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about a video inside a UIView, but you can use an UIImageView and animate a series of images with it. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCsumlHiEc0)'s how.

Comment: This is the correct answer - Zippo most likely did use this exact solution.